# Unpack a list of dictionaries to an object in Python

Tags: python, unpack

I am not sure how to ask this as I'm not sure if I'm using the proper key words. I have a dictionaries in a variable `x`. I unpack (is that the right term?) to a object of type `Org` like so:

```py
org = Org(**x)
```

where `x` is of the form:

```
{'user': 'joe@example.com', 'sk': 'meta_3', 'location': 'Dubai', 'name': 'Thomas'}
```

This works so far. I get an object `org` of type `Org`.

But my Q is: how do I handle if `x` is a list of dicts i.e. `x` is

```
[
  {'user': 'joe@example.com', 'sk': 'meta_3', 'location': 'Dubai', 'name': 'Thomas'},
  {'user': 'sam@example.com', 'sk': 'meta_4', 'location': 'Spain', 'name': 'Sam'}
]
```

How do I unpack that to a list of `Org` objects?

Comment: use a for loop?

Comment: ```[Org(**x) for x in list_of_x]```, where `list_of_x` is your list of dictionaries.

Comment: Do you want to get a list of `Org` objects, or collect all dicts in the list in to one `Org` object?

Comment: Thank you! List comprehension. I didn't know if python had some other magic to do this. This helps thank you

Comment: @LevM. I wanted a list of `Org` objects. I wasn't sure if there was a **** function other than doing a loop or list comprehension. Hence the post.

Comment: Then look like List comprehension is your friend, `****` operator can't exist, because in your case it would have to perform 2 different operations: create a list of custom objects based on outer container, than unpack the inner container for constructor arguments of `Org`. I can see no reasonable way Python developers could predict such a use case and develop a shortcut or specific command for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `x_list` is your list containing dicts:

```
org_list = []
for x in x_list:
    org = Org(**x)
    org_list.append(org)
```

Now you have a list `org_list` that contains all created Org objects.

Comment: Thank you, a compact one I found was list comprehension:

`[Org(**x) for x in x__list]`

Comment: Yes, that works great! I always find list comprehension a bit scuffed to read if you are new to Python, so I try to write the full loop when commenting on StackOverflow. a bit more readable. Nice you found a solution!